# Added SSD showing as System Reserved?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have a 120GB SSD with my Win7 64 on it, a 60GB data drive.

I just tried to add another 120SSD, plugged it al in, turned my PC on and it shows up as a System Reserved disk (E:)

How do I just have it show as an extra 120GB disk?

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the drive (E:). This may clear it up and release your gigs.